# Jquery Mobile CSS Android Styling Boarders Not Showing On Button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, button

Hopefully this will be an easy one. Using the following styling to generate a Android Menu Style button ( ie with a thicker coloured bar on the botton when active or highlighted. )

How ever none of the CSS styling seems to make a change to it. I have the right class assigned to the button. Is the boarder example I am using below supported and if so is my syntax right ? If so any thoughts on potential issues ?

I am currently on the latest release of Jquery Mobile.

Thanks Terran

```
.ui-btn-active-androidmenu {
    border: 1px 1px 5px 1px solid #155678 /*{global-active-border}*/;
    z-index: 6;
    background: #387bbe /*{global-active-background-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: transparent /*{global-active-color}*/;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{global-active-shadow-x}*/ -1px /*{global-active-shadow-y}*/ 1px /*{global-active-shadow-radius}*/ #145072 /*{global-active-shadow-color}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/), to( #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/, #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/, #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/, #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/, #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #85bae4 /*{global-active-background-start}*/, #5393c5 /*{global-active-background-end}*/);
     font-family:"RobotoRegular";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error on the 'border' (5x, instead of 5px) option. That's going to cause issues with all CSS in that block, and perhaps even any CSS below that syntax error.

Comment: Thanks - that was human error when posting on here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Syntax Error on `border`:

The `border` won't take individual width. Please declare this way:

```
border: 1px solid #155678;
border-width: 1px 1px 5px 1px;
```